# How to save this list of windows running application to json

Tags: python, win32gui

I'm trying to list all the application running in my windows pc, i manage to list them all but in my json file i got 1 item how to save all of my running application to json?

here is the code:

```
import json

import win32gui



def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            app_list = [win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)]
            with open('application_running.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(list(app_list),f)
                print('Data Saved')
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
    
 

list_window_names()
```

i got one item in json file:

```
["Program Manager"]
```

but the application that runs in my windows pc is multiple how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `EnumWindows` loops through every window using the given function, so every window calls the function `winEnumHandler`. However, you are opening the same JSON file every time you save the window, thus the file is overwritten, and you see only one program.

To solve this, I declare a global variable `LIST_PROGRAMS`. Every loop will append the window name to the list, and then I just simply save that list.

```py
import json
import win32gui

LIST_PROGRAMS = []

def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            app_list = [win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)]
            global LIST_PROGRAMS
            LIST_PROGRAMS.append(list(app_list))
            print('Program added')
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
    with open('application_running.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dumps(LIST_PROGRAMS, f)
        print('Data Saved')
    
list_window_names()
```